# Recover files from RAW Drive in Windows

Tags: data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, raw

Portable USB Hardrive get corrupted (Bad sectors) and now is detecting as RAW.
I'm trying to find golden solution to deal with this so Everyone including me will have example what to do to recover files. I'm working on WINDOWS 7.

What I tried (and failed):

Step 1) To not damage HDD even harder I though the best to do is Clone HDD into image. I used `Data rescue DD` which created image file as "DD" format (*.dd).
Is the any other program which can Clone RAW HDD into different image format?

Step 2) Found only one program which can handle DD image format without mounting:
- `TestDisk 7.0-WIP` - This program couldn't find any partitions
Is the any other program which can work on DD file (RAW HDD) directly?

Step 3) I found only one program which can mount DD file:
- `PassMark OSFMount` - This program mounts DD File as selected drive letter but not every recovery program detects this drive.
Is the any other program which can mount DD file?

Step 4) For recovery from mounted DD Image I used:

Bellow programs doesn't detect mounted image:

- `Zero Assumption Recovery (ZAR 9.2 build 2)`
- `Undelete 360 (ver 2.16.25)`
- `Get Data Back (ver 1.02)`
- `EaseUs Recovery Wizard (ver 8.0)`
- `iCare Data Recovery Standard Version (ver 5.1)`

Bellow programs detects mounted image but can't handle RAW Drive:

- `Stellar Phoenix Windows Data Recovery (ver 6.0)`
- `Photo Rescue Pro (ver 4.5.2 build 201)`
- `Recuva (ver 1.49.1019)`
- `Orion File Recovery Software (ver 1.11)`
- `R-Studio (ver 5.4.134259)`

Is there any other program that can handle mounted DD RAW Drive?

Comment: check this out for product recommendation: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

OFSmount. It works in Windows.
OSForensics can access the mounted DD file.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Linux so that raw disk image files can be mounted easily just typing **"mount rawDisk.dd /tmp/myMountPoint"**.

But, Your question is for win 7 platform. For this situation I suggest to tell us what you wanna do after you mount the raw disk image. Because every user doesn't know every platform but its core is so similar. Also what you see in testdisk program. Because testdisk can read almost every disk format like fat,fat32,NTFS,ext2,3,4 and so on. If you wanna search a file when there is nothing shown while testdisk scan, I recommend to use **photorec** (usually comes with testdisk) for any extension of file. Like jpg,mp4 and so on.

Answer (score -1):

> This tool works under Linux, you might try it

[Link](https://www.easeus.com/disk-copy/clone-resource/linux-clone-hdd-to-ssd.html)

or this

[Link 2](http://www.hddguru.com/software/HDD-Raw-Copy-Tool/)

The second one can do :
Data recovery: make a copy of the damaged drive to attempt recovery on the copy
Data recovery: copy a damaged hard drive and skip bad sectors
Migration: completely migrate from one hard drive to another

It has to do some work for you